# Sequence 2 Animations That Loop With Delay In-Between

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

Goal: Create a looping animation with 2 overlapping `uilabels` to show one and hide the other by setting alphas respectively to 1 and 0.

Any tips would be appreciated.

What I've Tried:

1. Autoreverse/repeat animation - While this works, there is no delay in-between when the animation reverses and repeats itself.

   ```
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 3.0, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat]) {
            self.labelOne.alpha = 0
            self.labelTwo.alpha = 1
        }
    }
   ```
2. Recursive animation - This works, but when I re-enter the foreground from the background, the animation spazzes out showing/hiding each `uilabel`. My issue here is being unable to stop/reset the recursive animation.

   ```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 3.0, options: .curveLinear) {

                self.labelOne.alpha = 0
                self.labelTwo.alpha = 1
            } completion: { isComplete in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 3.0, options: [.curveLinear]) {
                    self.labelOne.alpha = 1
                    self.labelTwo.alpha = 0
                } completion: { isComplete in

                    self.runThisAnimation()
                }
            }
        }
   ```

Comment: Use key-frame animation

Comment: @RajaKishan do you have an example i might be able to follow?

Comment: No, you can search and there are many examples available.